# How can I retrieve events from my iphone calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to ask how to do it if it is possible.
Can you give me some sample codes or snippet on how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: When asking questions here, you'll get a much better response if you appear to have done some basic research yourself first. Asking a question here shouldn't be the first thing you try.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [Event Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), which has sample code as well as documentation on reading calendar events.

Answer (score 1):

Code to fetch all events.For more info you can use the above Event Kit apple documentation.

```
NSDate *start = ...
NSDate *finish = ...

// use Dictionary for remove duplicates produced by events covered more one year segment
NSMutableDictionary *eventsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1024];

NSDate* currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:start];

int seconds_in_year = 60*60*24*365;

// enumerate events by one year segment because iOS do not support predicate longer than 4 year !
while ([currentStart compare:finish] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDate* currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds_in_year sinceDate:currentStart];

    if ([currentFinish compare:finish] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:finish];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentStart endDate:currentFinish calendars:nil];
    [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
                                      usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {

                                          if (event) {
                                              [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:event.eventIdentifier];
                                          }

                                      }];       
    currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(seconds_in_year + 1) sinceDate:currentStart];

}

NSArray *events = [eventsDict allValues];
```